# Arrange two parent-child columns (Stories and Chapters) in a single result column hierarchy without duplicating the parent

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image: Table]

I have a table `Fables` as above with 2 columns `title` and `titledisplay`.
I need to get output like the following:

```
Story1
Chapter1.1
Chatper2.1
Story2
Story3
Story4
Chapter4.1
Chapter4.2
Chapter4.3
Story5
Chapter5.1
Chapter5.2
```

I tried the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title, TitleDisplay FROM Fables ORDER BY Title
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: sqlite is used for db

Comment: i think you got the answer. or you still not get what you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a UNION which selectively targets both columns. A pseudo order is required to ensure that the Stories are ahead of the Chapters:

```
SELECT x.TheColumn
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Title as TheColumn, Title, 1 AS MyOrder
    FROM Fables

  UNION

    SELECT TitleDisplay as TheColumn, Title, 2 AS MyOrder
    FROM Fables
    WHERE TitleDisplay IS NOT NULL
) x
ORDER BY x.Title, x.MyOrder, x.TheColumn;
```

This should work in most RDBMS. 
[MySql SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45d3d/2)

Comment: You are welcome - I see you've commented `sqlite` - the query works fine in [SqlLite as well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/45d3d/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below query

SELECT Title,TitleDisplay FROM Fables GROUP BY Title;